# Any downside to creating an object with "value":""

Tags: javascript, json

I'm keeping track of things in an array currently, but I don't need to know anything about them other than they're in the array. For example, I might have a forSale array, and I have all the itemIDs that are for sale in the array.

Works fine for now, but anyways, I've been doing some testing and it seems as if `object.hasOwnProperty(x)` blows `array.indexOf(x) !== -1` out of the water (I know they're completely different but I don't know of any other way to test if an array has a value in it). This got me to thinking, why not just create something like

```
var saleObject = {
    "someId" : "",
    "someOtherId" : ""
};
```

I can then call `saleObject.hasOwnProperty('someId')` and know that that object is on sale. I can see no downsides to this, but that's why I'm here. Is there anything wrong in doing this?

Comment: Note that you can also use the `in` keyword if you know that you're working with a plain object: `"someOtherId" in saleObject === true`

Comment: Since you're just keeping track of a list of items, I think an array suits you much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with it at all assuming you can modify the dependent code to accept the new structure.  The difference in speed stems from the Object being able to do a Binary Search to determine whether it's got the key, whereas the indexOf has to check every value in the array.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's a valid use of an object being that JavaScript objects are only enhanced associative arrays.

Also note that `Array.indexOf` is not a standard JavaScript method at this moment and you can't rely on it. It was introduced only in ECMA-262 edition 5.